# How many variants of the "Was Karman wrong?" question is enough for one user?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In addition to my answer there, I've just added the comment

> `-1` "If von Kármán is right with his description of the Kármán line..." That sentence **misrepresents the reality** of the situation. Karman did not *describe* the Karman line, he *defined* it. Definitions can be whatever you want them to be. They aren't "right' or "wrong", but only "useful" or "not-useful/obscure". This one ended up in the useful category for a half-century. Because the OP has been at this "was Karman wrong" question writing **for so long now**, I think this question should be closed as "math-trolling not good faith question-asking".

to the question [Can it be calculated that near the Kármán line the lifting force equals the centrifugal force?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31738/12102)

A reading of the question (currently at 5 down votes, zero up votes) shows it to be either misleading, or trivial ('please calculate the following cases for me').

There's a history:

- **+4**/-0 [Are there calculations regarding the Kármán line in the Theodore von Kármán collection?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31669/12102)
- **+4**/-2 [Is the equation below the right one for an airplane flying at the Kármán line altitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33106/12102)
- **+2**/-1 [At what conference the “von Kármán line” arose and was discussed for the first time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31572/12102)
- **+1**/-1 [Is it correct to use the vis-viva equation when there are two forces acting on the orbiting body? **[CLOSED]**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32962/12102)
- **-2**/+0 [Can the question below ignore the acceleration downwards to the centre of the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33557/20636)
- **-4**/+1 [Can the centrifugal force still be ignored as it appears that the lift force is a small fraction of it at the Kármán line altitude?**[DUPLICATE]**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33535/12102)
- **-3**/+1 [Is it correct to apply the vis-viva equation to an airplane that flies in a straight line at the Kármán line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32935/12102)
- **-3**/+1 [Where does the definition of the Kármán line on Wikipedia come from?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32976/12102)
- **-4**/+1 [Does an airplane in orbit near the Kármán line altitude, with the air providing lift, ever reach orbital velocity? **[DUPLICATE]**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33344/12102)
- **-5**/+2 [Can it be calculated that near the Kármán line the lifting force equals the centrifugal force?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31738/12102)
- **-7**/+1 [Does a credible Kármán plane reach escape velocity within a minute or does it follow the curvature of the Earth? **[DUPLICATE]**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33081/12102)
- **-8**/+2 [Is the definition of the Kármán line from Wikipedia right? **[CLOSED]**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31461/12102)

as well as my previous meta question

- [Did the editing of this post go way overboard, like “six-sigma” overboard?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1074/12102)

I feel that this focus by one user on asking one variant after another of "Was Karman wrong? in question after question, with little or no progress, insightful disussions about previous answers received or attempts to build upon previous answers is no longer an effort to use Stack Exchange question posts *properly and in good faith.* I feel these question are being used by the OP instead to push a point.

There isn't any hard limit to follow-up questions in SE as long as they are good questions, but after a series of posts that do not seem to be good questions, and certainly show no growth or evolution by making use of the previous answers received, I wonder if *this specific line of questioning* might benefit from a short pause for review? The users other questions are usually really interesting and thought provoking, I'm only asking about the Karman-math series.

Are any other users finding this ever-expanding series of questions continuing to be productive and reasonable?

Comment: These questions are not about "Was Von Kármán wrong ?" . On the contrary i'm a big supporter of Von Kármán because he didn't ignore the centrifugal force like you did time after time when i asked a question regarding this topic.

Comment: @Conelisinspace a meta question like this is an invitation for others to express opinions on the topic raised, and that certainly includes you (it's why I left a link there to this question for you!) So your thoughts are most welcome of course. Consider formulating a reply in the form of an answer and posting.

Comment: @called2voyage  Yeah, i think i don't have to defend myself for anything here.

Comment: @Conelisinspace Actually, I think you do. I agree with uhoh that your focus does not seem to be in good faith, and that is compromising the quality of your questions. Your last five questions on the topic have negative score. Before uhoh made this meta post, I was already growing concerned about this direction.

Comment: @called2voyage  Sometimes, some people, like me, have to ask many questions to understand a specific topic. Especially many questions  arise then, when you are hindered by people who are eager to close those questions Then you have to ask new ones, slightly different,  to understand that specific topic.

Comment: @Conelisinspace -5 and -8 scores are not a blip. These are not just some users with an axe to grind. I think you need to seriously evaluate whether there is a better way you can go about this quest for knowledge, or give this line of inquiry a rest.

Comment: @ If I understand correctly the OP questions if my posts are properly and in good faith because they are used to push a point. Don't get me wrong, i think good faith is a good thing in relations, but why have questions to be asked in good faith ?  And why should I not ask questions to make a point ? What's wrong with that ? If a contributor has a bad feeling about a question, why should he not just ignore it ?

Comment: @Conelisinspace You're ignoring the main thrust of my comments which is that whatever is happening, it is affecting the quality of your posts. That is why they are getting downvoted and closed.

Comment: @called2voyage Understood, thank you for the concern.

Comment: This "Karman" stuff is the first thing that's driven me to use "ignore tags" on space stackexchange.

Comment: bring back "why does insight look wet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1143/12102) @Hobbes points out that *collaboration* is an important and valuable element of the Stack Exchange magic. Whether voluntary or not, I think that's what's happened here.

Thought the journey was a bit bumpy, the ninth question in the series of K-questions [Is the equation showed below the right one for an airplane flying at the Kármán line altitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33106/12102) converged to a really well-formulated and written question.

I like this one in particular because it doesn't seem to try to prove a point, but instead asks a genuine question in good faith. *In scenario X, which one (if any) of these equations would yield Y?*

It was an exciting, bumpy flight, hopefully now we'll have smooth sailing (I love mixed metaphors).